# Need an explanation of an item in the linux strace out file

Tags: linux, strace

Among the strace records, there is the following open log. Please explain the meaning of the hexadecimal number at the location of the file name.

3967  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

3967  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

3967  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

3967  open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3

...

4040  open(**0x7f150da8cfa0**, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_APPEND|O_CLOEXEC, 0666) = 8

3967  open("/dev/shm/sem.F7rPtU", O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 4

4040  open(**0x7f150da8cfa0**, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5

4040  open(**0x7ffe0f48bb80**, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_EXCL, 0600) = 5

4040  open(**0x7f1511d092c0**, O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 5

4041  open(**0x74ce13**, O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 9

Comment: What is your version of strace ? Are you using GLIBC ? Because in recent versions, open() is a wrapper on top of openat(). Hence, strace should make appear calls to openat() not open().

Comment: @ Rachid, Thanks for your interest. 
Version of strace is 4.8
the linux using is Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-148-generic x86_64)
I used strace while building linux image of an ARM based CPU such as below:
strace -f -e trace=open -o ../strace_out.txt bitbake linux-euto-v9

Comment: I suspect the hex values are addresses within the symbol table for the process that likely maps to string-literal addresses whether the actual path is located.

Comment: After a quick look at the strace [source code](https://github.com/strace/strace), the address of the string is displayed when strace is unable to find a terminating '\0' char at the end of the string (it scans the string up to a maximum length).

Comment: Thank you! 
What is the maximum length value and is it possible to change this value with the command line option? The purpose is to see the file path/name.